# Is there a way, without using eval(), to read a local PHP file pre-parsed into resulting HTML?

Tags: php, parsing, local-files

This seems like it should be an obvious, quick solution, but that's not turning out to be the case.

I have a local file that does some database work and outputs HTML, let's call this `file1`. I have another file that needs to use some of this information, but shouldn't need to generate it itself, `file2`.

My plan was to just pull the pre-parsed PHP (at this point HTML) into `file2`, but it's pulling PHP code instead. This could obviously be handled with `eval()`, but I'd rather not. Something along the lines of `wget()` might do the trick, but I'd rather not run command line from my PHP script either if possible.

Is there a solution while avoiding the two options above or do I have to just bite the bullet and use one of them?

**Quick Clarification:** The entirety of `file1` is not used. `file2` chops out the parts it needs so simply outputting all resulting HTML from `file1` is not viable.

Comment: It sounds as if you should be using [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) if you want to access parts of file1 from file2

Comment: Where is the PHP code "in your HTML" coming from? Do you trust its source?

Comment: It's my own script so I do trust the content, yes.

Comment: @Dan: Does the code change often? Is the code coming from a database or...? It's still not clear to me what "pre-parsed PHP (at this point HTML)" means. Is it HTML or is it PHP?

Comment: @netcoder: The content does change often. Pre-parsed means that the PHP generates an HTML file. `file2` only needs access to that resulting HTML.

Comment: Write `file1` properly with some functions, include it, and call the functions as necessary . . .

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like the following to buffer the output and save it into a variable:

```
ob_start();
include "file1.php";
$content = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Now your `$content` will contained the 'echoed' output of your source file.

`ob_*` functions are content buffering family. They temporarily disable outputting data to the `STDOUT` and instead store echoed content inside a buffer. [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php).

[Example on Ideone](http://ideone.com/SFbh3)

Comment: I have run into the same abstract problem and I created a working solution by using the `include()`  the page and `get_my_content()` use a function in that page to generate the content.

Comment: @awashburn: This is another valid solution, I just dislike the requirement of encapsulating everything in the file inside a function (or being required to do anything with a function tbf) :)

Comment: Understandable, my function inside a file solution was clever, but a little messy. I like the approach these functions offer as a much "cleaner," though slightly esoteric, solution.

Comment: Totally agreed :) And at the end of the day everybody uses whatever they feel right with ;)

Answer (score 1):

file_get_contents("http://Full.URL");
And to make it pass 30 characters..

-- Edit --

Ok.

when you try file_get_contents on a URL, php will request the URL, just like a good-o-wget does. You can also use this to trigger scripts.

check http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php for more info.

Comment: It's a good solution. The only downside is that you have to request the file over `TCP` as `HTTP Request` for it to be processed (local reference will read source). This (especially if `FQDN` is specified) will take time to be sent and returned over the internet. Possibly using `localhost/PATH` would speed things up as the request stays within intranet.